# Is there a faster way to compute the residues of this function,

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\frac{z^2log(z)}{1+z^4}$$

I have that this function has simple poles at

$$e^{i\pi/4},e^{i3\pi/4},e^{i5\pi/4},e^{i7\pi/4}$$

which are the zeroes of the denominator (1+$z^4$).

The computation of the residues is taking a very long time -- is there a simpler way to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Shouldn't the residues be just $\log(z)/(4z)$ evaluated at the 4 simple poles, once you've chosen a branch for the log? Why is that taking a long time?

Comment: How do you get log(z)/4(z) @wltrup?  Are you using lim f(z)(z-zj), for the four poles z_j, i.e. the zeroes of (1+z^4)?  Thanks,

Comment: Yes. See [residue at a simple pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles)

Comment: Hi @wltrup, that is the formula that I am using.  Did you simplify your f(z)?  E.g., did you divide top and bottom by the z^2 factor?  (and, if you used L'Hopital's rule, shouldn't it be 4z^3?)

Comment: Residue at $z_k$: $z^2\log(z)/(1+z^4)'$ computed at $z=z_k$. $z^2\log(z)/(1+z^4)' = z^2\log(z)/(4z^3) = \log(z)/(4z)$ then set $z=z_k$.

Comment: Oh, very cool - I did not know of this much simpler formula for quotients, where top and bottom are both holomorphic near the pole.  Thanks so much.  I was mindlessly cranking out the computations, using L'H rule, etc and getting messy results.  Have a great night @wltrup.

Comment: Yes, it's very useful. The result for higher-order poles is useful too.

Comment: Hi @wltrup - can I ask you one more question, since you brought up the result for higher-order poles?  A previous problem that I solved required the computation of a residue at a pole of order 3.  So, I went straight for the computation of f's Laurent series.  But that was also quite a bit of computation.  The series was something similar to $\frac{1}{z^3(e^z+1)}$, so, the denominator's series expansion is easily gotten, but then the 1 in the numerator makes the computation pretty bad -- I had to use polynomial long-division until the 1/z term appeared.  Do you think there's a better way?

Comment: Read the link I posted earlier. In particular, the section immediately following it.